# Generate a sequence of sequences

Tags: sequence

Imagine I have a sequence of M integers each of which is either zero or one. How do I generate a sequence of all such 2^M sequences?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can also use `Tuples`:

```
m = 5;
Tuples[{0, 1}, m]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Look up [`IntegerDigits`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/IntegerDigits.html).

```
m = 5;

IntegerDigits[Range[0, 2^m - 1], 2, m]
```